# Refuse Calls - missing button

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone5S running iOS 12.5.4.

Recently I have been getting annoying calls from my "ISP" threatening cut off my internet.
I would block these, but they use a different number each time (often not even a valid number).

I would like to be able to refuse calls from suspicious looking unknown callers until they give up, but only have a "Slide to Answer" button.
An Apple help site suggested double tap to cancel, but this doesn't work.

---

Thanks to those who answered. Unfortunately I have been unable to test, as the nuisance caller has stopped. (I mainly use the iPhone for outgoing calls, and only get calls from family or a few trusted contacts.)

Comment: Wasn't it one push on the power button for decline call?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: And I assume that you are aware of the possibility to silence/send to voicemail all unknown callers?

Comment: I once accidentally did a recall on one of these (censored).  iPhone started dialing a number different than shown.  That tells me that AT&T is able to detect a forged caller ID and therefore ought to be blocking them!

Answer (score 1):

> #### Decline a call and send it directly to voicemail
>
> Press the […] Sleep/Wake button […] twice quickly.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph3c9947bf/ios

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is locked, only slide to answer is present. You have to click the lock button once to silence, and twice to decline it. If it's unlocked, you can decline it normally.

[More details here](https://www.businessinsider.com/iphone-cant-decline-an-incoming-call-2016-2?r=US&IR=T)